# Can anybody explain these examples?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am just getting started with electronics coming from a web dev background so this is a beginner question.

I am following this [tutorial](https://makeabilitylab.github.io/physcomp/electronics/series-parallel.html#step-4-solve-for-i_1-and-i_2) and I'm confused about this part! The paragraph under step 4 has me very confused so I have a few questions:

---

- Sentence that confuses me: *10 times as much current flows through the **I2** branch as the **I1** branch*
- My question: According to the image above the paragraph, 90mA is running through ***I1***, and only 9mA is running through ***I2***. Shouldn't 10 times as much current be flowing through ***I1*** than on ***I2***?

---

- Sentence that confuses me: *the ratio of the two resistors R1 to R2—R2 is 10 times larger than R1*
- My question: What exactly does it mean by the ratio of ***R1*** to ***R2—R2***, would that mean that R1:0 is 10 times greater than R1? `—` doesn't seem to be a minus sign, if it's not then what is it?

Comment: for your last question, the "-" is a dash, not a minus sign.  I would write that like: "...the ratio of the two resistors R1 to R2. R2 is 10 times larger than R1.", replacing the dash with a period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

1. ***question****: According to the image above the paragraph, 90mA is running through I1, and only 9mA is running through I2. Shouldn't 10 times as much current be flowing through I1 than on I2?*            ........Yes.

I think it's pretty clear there typos or editing mistakes here. Not only is \$I_{1}\$ (\$90mA\$) 10 times greater than \$I_{2}\$ (\$9mA\$), but just looking at the equations to the right, both branches can not both use \$R_{1}\$ in the denominator and have different results!

2. ***question**:*What exactly does it mean by the ratio of R1 to R2—R2, would that mean that R1:0 is 10 times greater than R1? — doesn't seem to be a minus sign, if it's not then what is it?*

\$R_{2}\$ is 10 times greater than \$R_{1}\$, so the ratio \$ \frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}}\$ is 10. A higher resistance means we just expect 10 times more current to be restricted in the \$R_{2}\$ branch, than can flow in the \$R_{1}\$ branch. Or conversely, we just expect 10 times more current to be flow in the \$R_{1}\$ branch, than can flow in the \$R_{2}\$ branch. Which matches what we would expect with proper use of Ohm's law.

Alternatively, \$I_{1} = \frac{V_{A}}{R_{1}}\$ and
\$I_{2} = \frac{V_{A}}{R_{2}}\$. Setting both sides equal to \$V_{A}\$ leads to \$ \frac{R_1}{R_2} = \frac{I_2}{I_1}\$ so \$\frac{1}{10} = \frac{9mA}{90mA}\$.

Comment: The reason for your confusion in question 2 is that the answer was not worded very well.  Here's a possible rephrasing:

"Indeed, this exactly matches the ratio of the two resistors R1 and R2:  R2 is 10 times larger than R1 and thus will restrict far more current."